# How to prevent an order from being cancelled using event observer?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am using the following code to prevent the order from being cancelled from the Magento admin panel.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Muk_OrderCancel>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Muk_OrderCancel>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ordercancel>
                <class>Muk_OrderCancel_Model</class>
            </ordercancel>
        </models>
        <events>
             <sales_order_save_before>
                <observers>
                     <ordercancel>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Muk_OrderCancel_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>canCancelOrder</method>
                     </ordercancel>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_before>
        </events>
        <helpers>
            <ordercancel>
                <class>Muk_OrderCancel_Model_Helper</class>
            </ordercancel>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

In the observer I am using the following code:

```
<?php
class Muk_OrderCancel_Model_Observer
{
    public function canCancelOrder( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {        
        $incrementId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData('increment_id');

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

        $adminUserSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

        $adminUserId = $adminUserSession->getUser()->getUserId();

        $adminUserName = $adminUserSession->getUser()->getUsername();

        $adminRoleName = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminUserId)
                ->getRole()->getData('role_name');        

        if($adminRoleName) { //some condition            
            $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, false);            
        }       
    }
}
```

But even after enabling this module, the order is getting cancelled.

How can I prevent the order from being cancelled?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: @MarkoNovakovic I have cleared caches and the control is going to the method in the observer,But order is still cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController" "cancelAction" it goes:

```
$order->cancel()
       ->save();
```

which means the order is first cancelled then your observer fires. Although I found this event:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_payment_cancel', array('payment' => $this));
```

in "Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment" which fires before: "Mage_Sales_Model_Order" : "registerCancellation" method.

In your observer method which fires on this event you can do this:

```
if ($adminRoleName) {
$payment = $observer-&gt;getEvent()-&gt;getPayment();
$order = $payment-&gt;getOrder();
$order-&gt;setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, false);
//Get the existing non cancelled orders if they exist, if not create the array and add it to the admin session.
$orderIds = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')-&gt;getNonCancelledOrders();
if (!$orderIds) {
    $orderIds = array($order-&gt;getId());
} else {
    $orderIds[] = $order-&gt;getId();
}
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')-&gt;setNonCancelledOrders($orderIds);
}
```

Next, add one more observer in your etc/config.xml file on the following event: "controller_action_predispatch":

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
    <observers>
         <check_session_message>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Muk_OrderCancel_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>checkSessionMessage</method>
         </check_session_message>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch>
```

Then in your observer method:

```
public function checkSessionMessage($observer)
{
    //Check if we have admin order view or grid action
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $module = $request->getModuleName();
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    if ($module == 'admin' && $controller == 'sales_order') {
        if ($action == 'view' || $action == 'index') {
            //Check if we have orderIds
            $orderIds = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getNonCancelledOrders();
            if ($orderIds && count($orderIds) > 0) {
                //Unset them from the session
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->unsNonCancelledOrders();
                //Clear success message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getMessages(true);
                //Add error message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('You are not allowed to cancel the order(s)');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But If I try to cancel order from order grid page it shows exception page.How can I prevent it to happen?

Comment: Sorry, that's because of the Mage::throwException at the end, I have added it to prevent giving the user success message that order has been cancelled instead of showing the warning. You can remove that line from the code but you will have to find a way how to show proper warning or success message. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I will try , if you find any solution for this please update answer.